# Amazon Micro-instance for placeholder sites

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a little experience with Amazon EC2 and setting up a free micro instance

and I started thinking about other sites I own on traditional web hosting, where you pay X/month, don't really market for traffic and just show clients that you have a presence on the web.

Would EC2 be 'better' for that since the micro-instance is free until you get traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have in mind, that micro instances does not have the same performance all the time.
   http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html
2. Amazon gives you for free only 30GB of space for all system.
3. It's not service, so any instance shutdown means inaccessibility of your services.
4. It's like VPS, you have to take care of machine and set all things by yourself.

Comment: I thought micro instances don't shutdown unless you shut them down. I was thinking small simple sites with no functionality outside of hardcoded html and css could benefit

Comment: If you're looking at static html and css, then take a look at using S3 instead of EC2 instances.

Comment: okay, they have free tier as well?

Comment: It's true, but I have experienced an about one-hour-shutdown with no reason from Amazon. Probably hardware issue.

@UP: free tier: http://aws.amazon.com/free/